# How to store input strings from an user and store them in a pointer array?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

In my code, I am trying to get strings as input from the user and store them in a pointer array. But, my code stores only the last entered string in all the elements of the pointer array. What modifications do I have to do?

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    char *names[ 4 ], name[ 10 ];

    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
    
        printf( "Enter your name: " );
        scanf( "%s", name );
        names[ i ] = name;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        printf( "\n* %s", names[ i ] );
}
```

> The output is:
>
> Enter your name: Anna
> Enter your name: Michelin
> Enter your name: Steven
> Enter your name: Jacob
>
> - Jacob
> - Jacob
> - Jacob
> - Jacob

Comment: `names[ i ] = name;` is not doing what you think. You need to use `strcpy` or similar. You also need to allocate memory for the strings in `names`. At the moment these are just 4 pointers, which you assign to the fixed address of `name`. You can change `names` to be a `char names[10][4];`.

Comment: @Fe2O3 oops. You are right - it should be `char names[4][10];`.

Comment: Argh! [`scanf( "%s", name )` is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf)!

Comment: Please do not use `void main()`! It is deprecated for ages, unless you are writing a OS kernel...

Answer (score 2):

### Shallow Vs deep copy:

Given two pointers p and q, the statement:

```
p = q;
```

doesn't copy the contents of the memory pointed to by `q` to the contents of the memory pointed to by `p`. It copies the pointer values, such that both `p` and `q` now point to the same memory, and any change to the memory via `p` is reflected when `q` is used.
This is referred to as a shallow copy.

---

The statement

```
char *names[ 4 ];
```

declares an array of 4 pointers to `char`. NB that this only allocated memory for the pointers.

---

Then, in the loop:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
    
        printf( "Enter your name: " );
        scanf( "%s", name );
        names[ i ] = name;
}
```

You assign the address of the buffer `name` to each pointer in the array.

**Question:** What are the contents of `name` after the last iteration?

**Answer:** Jacob.

In memory, it'll look something like this:

````
names[0] ----
            |
names[1] ----
            |----> address of ```name```
names[2] ----
            |
names[3] ----
````

Dereferencing and printing the contents of those pointers, then, prints `Jacob` every time.

**Possible fixes:**

- Use a 2-dimensional array as the comments suggest.
- Allocate memory for the strings with `malloc` and assign their address to the pointers. Then you can use `strcpy` or POSIX's `strdup` to copy the contents of the buffer `name` to the memory region pointed to by each pointer (this is referred to as a deep copy).

*Note:* `strdup` uses `malloc` to allocate memory for the strings, so don't forget to `free` it.

> The strdup() function returns a pointer to a new string which is
> a duplicate of the string s.  Memory for the new string is
> obtained with malloc(3), and can be freed with free(3). (Linux's man page)

---

### Incorrect definition of `main()`

From C11:

> The function called at program startup is named main. The
> implementation declares no prototype for this function. **It shall be
> defined with a return type of int** and with no parameters:

```
int main (void) 
{ /* ... */ }
```

> or with two parameters (referred to here as
> argc and argv, though any names may be used, as they are local to the
> function in which they are declared):

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ /* ... */ }
```

> or equivalent; or in some other implementation-defined manner.

---

### Buffer-overflow vulnerability:

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

is equivalent to:

```
gets(name);
```

It will happily continue to read input and overflow the buffer.

Instead, consider using `fgets`:

```
fgets (name, sizeof (name), stdin);
```

`fgets` reads at most `n - 1` characters, and null-terminates the string.

Or use a width specifier with `scanf`:

```
scanf("%9s", name);
```